# MYSQL SUM returning blank when should be 0

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey I am just wondering why the following query is returning blank spaces in my table instead of a 0?, because there is nothing inside the driver_stats table at the moment it should return 0? any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

```
   SELECT 
    SUM(IF(qual_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS poles,
    SUM(IF(race_pos <= '3', 1,0)) AS podiums,
    SUM(IF(race_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS victories,
    SUM(overtakes) AS overtakes
     FROM driver_stats s
     left join drivers d on d.drivers_id = s.drivers_id
    WHERE d.team_id = '$row[team_id]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you change the `left join` to a `right join`? Or just move your query around so it's

```
drivers d left join driver_stats s
```

Comment: ha yeah that works fine! thanks very much, can't believe I missed it.

Comment: Will works, but can be a problem, depending on driver_stats table.

Answer (score 0):

If you `SUM()` zero things in SQL, the result is `NULL`. I agree with you that it would be more sensible for the answer to be zero, but that is how it is. I suggest using

```
COALESCE(SUM(IF(qual_pos = '1', 1,0)), 0) AS poles
```

Comment: thanks a lot, yeah I am using COALESCE on my other sums where there no conditions. I changed the join around below and its returning the 0's now. Thanks for your time.